# How to "know" of iisreset on a webservice

Tags: iis, web-services

I have a webservice where I want to do something when a the application pool ends, so I thought I'd do:

```
Application_End()
{
    // Some logic here
}
```

What happens is if I stop the application pool, this logic is executed. 
On the other hand, if I just call iisreset, it is NOT.

So my question is: where should I put my code so that it is executed in both cases?

Comment: Are you referring to a WCF service, or to a legacy ASMX service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that Application_End will be called. The example you mentioned, where you perform an IIS reset is an example. Other examples could include someone unplugging the server, or a hardware failure.

What I've done in the past is to use Application_Start to call my data cleanup logic as the application comes back online. This is assuming you don't need any values that were stored in memory.

Comment: Well, in order to do my cleanup I need the references I have in memory. I guess I will have to serialize them somehow so I can do the cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could.  Imagine if your code fired off an infinite loop, you could basically kill the web server and stop it shutting down.

Comment: Following that logic, doing the same in Application_End() would prevent an application pool from stopping, which would have similar impact. 

I won't say you're wrong. It just doesn't sound right.